# *ngFor and *ngIf together, Angular2, Ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to display list of options using ngFor but only fulfilling certain condition, is it possible to use ngFor and ngIf together to achieve that?
Something like this:

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="task">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let task of tasks" [value]="task" *ngIf="task.ProjectId == project.Id">{{task.Title}}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
```

Comment: did my answer fix your problem or do you need some additional help? If it fixed your problem, could you mark my answer as accepted?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

*ngFor and *ngIf cannot be used together on the same element.

What you can do is use an ng-container.

> `<ng-container>` is a logical container that can be used to group nodes
>   but is not rendered in the DOM tree as a node.
>
> `<ng-container>` is rendered as an HTML comment.

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="task">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let task of tasks">
        <ion-option [value]="task" *ngIf="task.ProjectId == project.Id">{{task.Title}}</ion-option>
    </ng-container>
</ion-select>
```

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to test that out

Comment: this answer might be correct but somehow this isn't working for me, there are no errors, but there is also nothing showing up

Comment: fixed this, now i am 100% sure this is working